# How to make system boot to text mode with high resolution and use startx to start KDE on Kubuntu?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, xorg, kde, multi-user

I've tried a few suggestions, but have hit walls each time with various odd issues and would like a clear and working strategy to make Kubuntu 20.04 start to a higher resolution text mode console with autologin and then be able to execute `startx` to start a KDE session.  I would also like to be able to use `control-alt-backspace` to kill xorg and return to the shell aside from logging out.

How can this be set this up properly?

Comment: I am on mobile so I can only give a hint change default target to multi-user target for the first